# override table background color in Buefy/Bulma

Tags: bulma, buefy

In an app that uses the Buefy component library (which uses the Bulma framework for the CSS), I've got the background color for table components set like so in the variables.scss file:

```
$contrast: #edebe4;

$table-background-color: $contrast;
```

This causes all table components to be displayed with the defined background color.  Now, I'd like to be able to override that color on a specific table component.  I haven't found anything in the Buefy or Bulma docs that show how to do this.  Is it possible?

I tried this but it didn't have any affect -

```
<b-table
    :data="data"
    :sticky-header="true"
    class="has-background-white"
>
```

Answer (score 0):

I met this case before and here is my solution:

- First, I wrap b-table in a section and assign an id for section tag

```
<section id="my-table">
    <b-table>
    ....
    </b-table>
</section>
```

- Then, in my style, I override the background color of table class:

```
<style scoped>
#my-table .table{
  background-color: white;
}
</style>
```

Comment: Your solution looks like it should work.  I tried it but it won't work in my app.  Not sure why.  In your app, where this is working, does it still work if the `.table` selector is removed from the rule?

Comment: No, the ```.table``` selector is compulsory, because Buefy puts property ```has-background-color``` inside class ```.table```.

Comment: Maybe you want to try to remove the word ```scoped``` in the style tag to make the style become global style. And you could also try to add the keyword important ```background-color: white !important;``` to override all previous styling rules.

Comment: I tried all of the suggestions except for global because the goal is to have a white table background only in this modal.  Alas, nothing seems to work to make it white.  Hopefully your answer will help other people though.